# Scaling canvas with scaleFocus causes jumps

Tags: java, android, android-animation, scale

I'm working on a custom view, that can be scaled with a scale gesture. When I wasn't using scale focus, everything worked fine. But once I did it like this `canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, scaleFocus[0], scaleFocus[1]);`, it caused jumps while scaling down to some low scale factor. Here is simplified version of the view, that illustrates the problem:

```
public class TestView extends FrameLayout {

private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleGestureDetector;
private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;
private float mMinScaleFactor = 0.4f;
private static final float MAX_SCALE_FACTOR = 2.0f;
private Matrix canvasMatrix = new Matrix();
float[] scaleFocus = new float[2];
private Rect clipBounds = new Rect();

private static final String TAG = "TestView";

public TestView(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context);
    sharedConstructor();
}

public TestView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    sharedConstructor();
}

public TestView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    sharedConstructor();
}

public void setChildViews() {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getContext());
    LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(StateUtil.screenWidth*2, StateUtil.screenHeight*2);
    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.test);
    canvasMatrix.set(getMatrix());

    addView(imageView);

    //some additional views are added here
}

private void sharedConstructor(){
    mScaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), mScaleGestureListener);

    setChildViews();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return mScaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event) || super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.getClipBounds(clipBounds);
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, scaleFocus[0], scaleFocus[1]);

    canvas.getMatrix().invert(canvasMatrix);
    canvas.save();
}

private final ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener mScaleGestureListener
        = new ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

        scaleFocus[0] = detector.getFocusX();
        scaleFocus[1] = detector.getFocusY();

        canvasMatrix.mapPoints(scaleFocus);
        if (clipBounds.contains((int) scaleFocus[0], (int) scaleFocus[1])){
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(mMinScaleFactor, Math.min(mScaleFactor, MAX_SCALE_FACTOR));
            TestView.this.invalidate();
        }

        return true;
    }
};
```

}

And here is what it looks like on my device:

[image]

I've tried solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35216036/android-canvas-scalefocus-causing-jumping-position) , but it doesn't work for me. Even when I don't call `super.onTouchEvent(event);`, problem still occurs.

Any ideas what causes it and how it can be solved?